# dependency arrow in bridge pattern

Tags: oop, design-patterns, dependencies, uml, class-diagram

[image]

Is the arrow read like "Arena depends on LeagueStore" ? How is this implemented ? [Here](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/6973/what-do-these-arrows-in-design-pattern-diagrams-mean) is a similar question, but it doesn't include such an arrow.

picture taken from [slide 9](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~lacher/courses/COP3331/design2.ppt)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The UML relationship "depends on" is deliberately wide in scope.  It means that some aspect of the "classifier" (class, interface, package, ...) referenced by the relationship is used by the classifier at the other end of the relationship.  This can include calling a method, using a type, including a package and so on.

In this case I think it can clearly be interpreted as "uses", that is, calls one or more of its methods.  Today, this relationship has its own UML representation as a stereotype called "uses" on the dependency relationship to make it a little more specific.

Answer (score 1):

The diagram is not a very good example of a bridge. The name comes from the whole idea that there are two hierarchies connected at the top. All this diagram is depicting is the fact that the outer class (Arena) manipulates the LeagueStore through an outer class. That's not even a pattern, that's the Envelope-Letter Idiom from Coplien's *Advanced C++*.

Bridge would be LeagueStore having a delegate inside (impl, as depicted), but then also having specializations of LeagueStore. For example, if you had a class called Report, it would have ReportImpl inside, that could have subclasses like JasperReport and BirtReport, but then Report could have subclasses like CrosstabReport.